# Understanding IEquatable

Tags: c#, iequatable

When I implement objects that I want to compare using the [`IEquatable<T>` interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.iequatable-1?view=netstandard-2.0):

1. Why do I have to override `Equals(object)` method if I already implemented `Equals(T)`?
2. Can I use `==` and `!=` operators once I implement `IEquatable<T>`?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

1. From [MS Docs article on `IEquatable<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.iequatable-1?view=netstandard-2.0):

   > If you implement `IEquatable<T>`, you should also override the
   >   base class implementations of
   >   `Equals(Object)` and
   >   `GetHashCode()` so that their behavior is
   >   consistent with that of the
   >   `Equals(T)`
   >   method. If you do override
   >   `Equals(Object)`, your
   >   overridden implementation is also
   >   called in calls to the static
   >   `Equals(Object, Object)`
   >   method on your class. In addition,
   >   you should overload the `op_Equality`
   >   and `op_Inequality` operators.
   >   This ensures that all tests for equality
   >   return consistent results.
2. No, [operators do not use the Equals method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1849288/712526). They must be [overloaded separately](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/overloadable-operators) to do so.

Comment: so when you are dealing with objects, is == assumed to only mean the exact same memory address (same instance)

Comment: Pretty much.  More info here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/53k8ybth(VS.80).aspx

Comment: No, use ReferenceEquals() for that purpose. The equality operator (==) usually means the same, but can be overriden (e.g. for Strings and the like).

Comment: Slight terminology correction - you can't *override* operators, but you can *overload* them.

Comment: Yes, you can overload == and != in and use them in conjunction with the IEquatable interface. But this needs to be done manually, it doesn't come automatically with IEquatable. The "No" in part 2 of the answer is actually incorrect. Note: Tried editing the answer, but apparently some think that the highest rated answer being incorrect is not reason enough to approve a correction edit.

Comment: @AlexKven Done! It's not that such an edit shouldn't be made; it's that you're expecting reviewers to re-do your own research, to verify your change. Sometimes, they may not even be familiar with the programming language in question.

Answer (score 44):

1) As Ray said, override `Equals(object)` to ensure consistency when the method is called from classes which don't know (statically) that you implement `IEquatable<T>`. For instance, the non-generic collections classes will use `Equals(object)` for comparisons. You should also override `GetHashCode()`.

2) Implementing `IEquatable<T>` doesn't overload the == and != operators automatically, but there's nothing to stop you from doing so, just like `System.String` does. You should document this very clearly if you do, however - and be careful when you make comparisons between other types of reference (e.g. MyType and Object) which will still use the identity comparison. I suspect it's not a great idea to do this unless it's going to be a very heavily used type in your code, where everyone will become very familiar with it *and* where the syntactic sugar of overloading == will really make a positive impact on readability.

Comment: Jon, is there any performance gain for an IEquatable<T> implementing type used for instance in a Collection<T>, calling the Contains method?

Comment: It will avoid casting, yes. For value types, it'll avoid boxing and unboxing as well. See the docs for Collection<T>.Contains - it uses EqualityComparer<T>.Default, which will use the IEquatable<T> implementation if possible.

Comment: Yes, it is not a good idea to overload operator == and != to provide value equality checks (vs the default reference equality check). The MSDN documentation suggests you only do it for immutable types. There are also issues involving interfaces and operator overloading.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/728434/operator-overloading-with-interface-based-programming-in-c for more on both issues.