# Operator Overloading with Interface-Based Programming in C#

Tags: c#, .net, operator-overloading, equals

### Background

I am using interface-based programming on a current project and have run into a problem when overloading operators (specifically the Equality and Inequality operators).

---

### Assumptions

- I'm using C# 3.0, .NET 3.5 and Visual Studio 2008

UPDATE - The Following Assumption was False!

- Requiring all comparisons to use Equals rather than operator== is not a viable solution, especially when passing your types to libraries (such as Collections).

The reason I was concerned about requiring Equals to be used rather than operator== is that I could not find anywhere in the .NET guidelines that it stated it would use Equals rather than operator== or even suggest it. However, after re-reading [Guidelines for Overriding Equals and Operator==](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173147.aspx) I have found this:

> By default, the operator == tests for reference equality by determining whether two references indicate the same object. Therefore, reference types do not have to implement operator == in order to gain this functionality. When a type is immutable, that is, the data that is contained in the instance cannot be changed, overloading operator == to compare value equality instead of reference equality can be useful because, as immutable objects, they can be considered the same as long as they have the same value. It is not a good idea to override operator == in non-immutable types.

and this [Equatable Interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131187.aspx)

> The IEquatable interface is used by generic collection objects such as Dictionary, List, and LinkedList when testing for equality in such methods as Contains, IndexOf, LastIndexOf, and Remove. It should be implemented for any object that might be stored in a generic collection.

---

### Contraints

- Any solution must not require casting the objects from their interfaces to their concrete types.

---

### Problem

- When ever both sides of the operator== are an interface, no operator== overload method signature from the underlying concrete types will match and thus the default Object operator== method will be called.
- When overloading an operator on a class, at least one of the parameters of the binary operator must be the containing type, otherwise a compiler error is generated (Error BC33021 http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/watt39ff.aspx)
- It's not possible to specify implementation on an interface

See Code and Output below demonstrating the issue.

---

### Question

**How do you provide proper operator overloads for your classes when using interface-base programming?**

---

### References

[== Operator (C# Reference)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/53k8ybth.aspx)

For predefined value types, the equality operator (==) returns true if the values of its operands are equal, false otherwise. For reference types other than string, == returns true if its two operands refer to the same object. For the string type, == compares the values of the strings.

---

### See Also

---

### Code

```
using System;

namespace OperatorOverloadsWithInterfaces
{
    public interface IAddress : IEquatable<IAddress>
    {
        string StreetName { get; set; }
        string City { get; set; }
        string State { get; set; }
    }

    public class Address : IAddress
    {
        private string _streetName;
        private string _city;
        private string _state;

        public Address(string city, string state, string streetName)
        {
            City = city;
            State = state;
            StreetName = streetName;
        }

        #region IAddress Members

        public virtual string StreetName
        {
            get { return _streetName; }
            set { _streetName = value; }
        }

        public virtual string City
        {
            get { return _city; }
            set { _city = value; }
        }

        public virtual string State
        {
            get { return _state; }
            set { _state = value; }
        }

        public static bool operator ==(Address lhs, Address rhs)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Address operator== overload called.");
            // If both sides of the argument are the same instance or null, they are equal
            if (Object.ReferenceEquals(lhs, rhs))
            {
                return true;
            }

            return lhs.Equals(rhs);
        }

        public static bool operator !=(Address lhs, Address rhs)
        {
            return !(lhs == rhs);
        }

        public override bool Equals(object obj)
        {
            // Use 'as' rather than a cast to get a null rather an exception
            // if the object isn't convertible
            Address address = obj as Address;
            return this.Equals(address);
        }

        public override int GetHashCode()
        {
            string composite = StreetName + City + State;
            return composite.GetHashCode();
        }

        #endregion

        #region IEquatable<IAddress> Members

        public virtual bool Equals(IAddress other)
        {
            // Per MSDN documentation, x.Equals(null) should return false
            if ((object)other == null)
            {
                return false;
            }

            return ((this.City == other.City)
                && (this.State == other.State)
                && (this.StreetName == other.StreetName));
        }

        #endregion
    }

    public class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            IAddress address1 = new Address("seattle", "washington", "Awesome St");
            IAddress address2 = new Address("seattle", "washington", "Awesome St");

            functionThatComparesAddresses(address1, address2);

            Console.Read();
        }

        public static void functionThatComparesAddresses(IAddress address1, IAddress address2)
        {
            if (address1 == address2)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Equal with the interfaces.");
            }

            if ((Address)address1 == address2)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Equal with Left-hand side cast.");
            }

            if (address1 == (Address)address2)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Equal with Right-hand side cast.");
            }

            if ((Address)address1 == (Address)address2)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Equal with both sides cast.");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

### Output

```
Address operator== overload called
Equal with both sides cast.
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on your second assumption?  Collection classes should use the .Equals() method.

Comment: +1 for clarity and details in question.

Comment: kvb - I updated my second assumption, and after reading John's answer and some more MSDN docs, the assumption is false. I've noted it above. Thanks!

Cyril - thank you!

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Short answer: I think your second assumption may be flawed. **`Equals()` is the right way to check for *semantic equality* of two objects, not `operator ==`.**

---

Long answer: Overload resolution for operators is *performed at compile time, not run time*.

Unless the compiler can definitively know the types of the objects it's applying an operator to, it won't compile. Since the compiler cannot be sure that an `IAddress` is going to be something that has an override for `==` defined, it falls back to the default `operator ==` implementation of `System.Object`.

**To see this more clearly, try defining an `operator +` for `Address` and adding two `IAddress` instances.** Unless you explicitly cast to `Address`, it will fail to compile. Why? Because the compiler can't tell that a particular `IAddress` is an `Address`, and there is no default `operator +` implementation to fall back to in `System.Object`.

---

Part of your frustration probably stems from the fact that `Object` implements an `operator ==`, and everything is an `Object`, so the compiler can successfully resolve operations like `a == b` for all types. When you overrode `==`, you expected to see the same behavior but didn't, and that's because the best match the compiler can find is the original `Object` implementation.

> Requiring all comparisons to use Equals rather than operator== is not a viable solution, especially when passing your types to libraries (such as Collections).

In my view, this is precisely what you should be doing. **`Equals()` is the right way to check for *semantic equality* of two objects.** Sometimes semantic equality is just reference equality, in which case you won't need to change anything. In other cases, as in your example, you'll override `Equals` when you need a stronger equality contract than reference equality. For example, you may want to consider two `Persons` equal if they have the same Social Security number, or two `Vehicles` equal if they have the same VIN.

But `Equals()` and `operator ==` are not the same thing. Whenever you need to override `operator ==`, you should override `Equals()`, but almost never the other way around. `operator ==` is more of a syntactical convenience. Some CLR languages (e.g. Visual Basic.NET) don't even permit you to override the equality operator.

Comment: Correct, after re-reading two of the MSDN documents, Equals is the correct way to check for value equality while operator== is for reference equality, unless perhaps it's an immutable type. I updated the notation for the second assumption with the documents that state my assumption is false. Thanks!

Comment: Glad I could help. Quick note: I like to use the phrase "semantic equality" rather than "value equality", since it's possible for two objects to have different values but still be considered equal (e.g., two postal addresses, where one uses "St" and the other uses "Street").

Comment: Good point! I've just been accustom to using value and reference since that's what MSDN uses. That isn't to say that what MSDN uses is always best or even correct.

Comment: Well, don't get me wrong -- value equality is definitely an accepted term. I just like to make the distinction clearer where I can.

Comment: actually, VB.NET does permit overriding the equality operator (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms379613%28VS.80%29.aspx) and is a better language to do so as it uses `Is` for reference equality instead of sharing `=` as C# does.

Comment: Actually, C# doesn't really overload the equality operator for `Object`.  Instead, there are two operators that `==` can represent--either an overloadable equality operator or a non-overloadable reference comparison--and C# will try to use the second when the first fails.  Not a design I like, since given `bool CheckEquals<T>(T p1, T p2) where T:class {return p1 == p2;}`, calling `CheckEquals("123", 123.ToString());` would check for reference identity rather than matching values, even though `==` with `String` normally compares values.  In something like VB.NET, ...

Comment: ...which uses a distinct "Is" operator, such a function would refuse to compile if one tried to use the equality-check operator; it would compile fine if one used `Is`, but in that case it would be obvious that it's testing for reference identity.

Comment: Interestingly it seems that the Microsoft docs still contradict each other. In the IEquatable<T> docs, they say that you should overload the equality/inequality operators if you override Equals(Object) - and don't mention any exceptions to this rule (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.iequatable-1?view=netframework-4.8#notes-to-implementers). The quote is "In addition, you should overload the op_Equality and op_Inequality operators. This ensures that all tests for equality return consistent results."

Comment: Continuing from my previous comment, the contradiction is that the Object.Equals docs suggest that reference types should only overload the operators in the case of immutable types intended to have value type semantics (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object.equals). The quote in this case is "Most reference types must not overload the equality operator, even if they override Equals. However, if you are implementing a reference type that is intended to have value semantics, such as a complex number type, you must override the equality operator."

Comment: To be clear I agree with this answer. I am going to follow the advice of not overloading the equality/inequality operators for reference types, except in the case of reference types that are immutable *and* are intended to be used like value types (which I interpret to mean that the other operators are to be overloaded also, e.g. addition, subtraction, etc). The advice from Microsoft in this case is more explicit, and makes logical sense, so I think it takes precedence over what the IEquatable<T> docs say.

Answer (score 4):

We ran into the same problem, and found an excellent solution: ReSharper custom patterns.

We configured ALL of our users to use a common global pattern catalog in addition to their own, and placed it into SVN so that it can be versioned and updated for everyone.

The catalog included all patterns known to be wrong in our system:

`$i1$ == $i2$`   (where i1 and i2 are *expressions* of our interface type, or derived.

the replace pattern is

`$i1$.Equals($i2$)`

and the severity is "Show as error".

Similarly we have `$i1$ != $i2$`

Hope this helps.
P.S. Global catalogs is the feature in ReSharper 6.1 (EAP), will be marked as final very soon.

**Update**: I filed a [ReSharper Issue](http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/RSRP-286954) to mark all interface '==' a warning unless it is comparing to null. Please vote if you think it is a worthy feature.

**Update2**: ReSharper also has [CannotApplyEqualityOperator] attribute that can help.

Comment: +1 For [CannotApplyEqualityOperator] attribute, useful on interfaces where reference equality is unlikely to be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

IMO this is a confusing design flaw in C#. IMO == should have been exactly the same as what is now `Equals` (basically there shouldn't have been an `Equals`) and if you wanted reference only equality instead you would call a specialized method like ReferenceEquals. This is compounded by language design flaws around operator overloading and inheritance - ie the ones you noted and the lack of extention method support for operators.