# Even if I know how/when to overload operator==, WHY should i do it?

Tags: c#

Assuming I am designing a collection of objects for use by others and assuming I have read and understood (huh?) most threads about the differences between operator== and Equals(), *WHY* should I ever implement operator==?

Stealing an example from [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1766492/c-sharp-overloading-operator-versus-equals), using it can be quite error prone:

```
object x = "hello";
object y = 'h' + "ello"; // ensure it's a different reference
(x == y); // evaluates to FALSE
string x = "hello";
string y = 'h' + "ello"; // ensure it's a different reference
(x == y); // evaluates to TRUE
```

So, can I tell my users to just use Equals() and ReferenceEquals() and that's it? What am I missing there?

- Are there maybe pieces of the standard code base that use == and there is no way around it?
- Is the == performance a lot better in some *important* cases? (well, ok, Equals is a virtual so it's gonna be a bit slower all the time, but i cannot see any use case where this actually becomes a bottleneck)
- something else?

Comment: ok, so it all comes down to syntactic sugar then. People like ==.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You *can* tell your users just to use `Equals`... but I for one find it *very* handy that various types (including `String`) overload `==`. Yes, you need to be aware of the way that overload resolution works, but for most experienced developers I suspect that *isn't* a problem most of the time, whereas:

```
if (Equals(x, y))
```

ends up looking nastier than

```
if (x == y)
```

in my view. Note that these are both different to

```
if (x.Equals(y))
```

which will blow up if `x` is null, of course...

If you prefer not to overload `==` then it's not like anything will fail - you just may get disgruntled users.

Answer (score 2):

You implement `==` as a convenience for the users of your API. If you feel so strongly that users of your API would be confused by it, then don't implement it. Personally I would disagree with you, but it's your decision at the end of the day.

Answer (score 0):

> *WHY* should I ever implement `operator==`?

For the convenience of the users of your type. If you are the only user, and you're happy to always test equality by invoking `Equals`, then you don't need to.

But if you were implementing, say, a complex number type<sup>1</sup>, I as a consumer of your type would be *extremely* disappointed to discover I *couldn't* do:

```
var z = new Complex(1, 0);
var c = new Complex(1, 0);
var eq = z == c;
```

but intead had to say

```
var eq = Complex.Equals(z, c);
```

---

<sup>1</sup> I know there is one...

Answer (score 0):

For me it's a question of what I generally want to do with the objects.

Take strings for example.
In 99% of all cases you compare two strings to check for equality and not whether both variables point to the same string.

You also write:

```
int x, y;
if( x == y ) ..
```

So why would you want to force yourself to use:

```
BigNum x, y;
if( x.Equals(y) ) ...
```

Of course it's a source of errors (as most operator overloading is), but I think given the right context (e.g. an object where it's obvious you'd want to compare it's value) then it's a good thing to overload.
If it's ambiguous then I'd always stick to Equals() and not overload ==.