# What's the difference between IEquatable and just overriding Object.Equals()?

Tags: c#, .net, equals, equality, iequatable

I want my `Food` class to be able to test whenever it is equal to another instance of `Food`. I will later use it against a List, and I want to use its `List.Contains()` method. Should I implement `IEquatable<Food>` or just override `Object.Equals()`? From MSDN:

> This method determines equality by
>   using the default equality comparer,
>   as defined by the object's
>   implementation of the
>   IEquatable.Equals  method for T
>   (the type of values in the list).

So my next question is: which functions/classes of the .NET framework make use of `Object.Equals()`? Should I use it in the first place?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Understanding IEquatable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/411500/understanding-iequatable)

Answer (score 270, accepted):

The main reason is performance. When generics were introduced in .NET 2.0 they were able to add a bunch of neat classes such as `List<T>`, `Dictionary<K,V>`, `HashSet<T>`, etc. These structures make heavy use of `GetHashCode` and `Equals`. But for value types this required boxing. `IEquatable<T>` lets a structure implement a strongly typed `Equals` method, so no boxing is required. Thus much better performance when using value types with generic collections.

Reference types don't benefit as much, but the `IEquatable<T>` implementation does let you avoid a cast from `System.Object` which can make a difference if it's called frequently.

As noted on [Jared Parson's blog](https://blog.paranoidcoding.org/2009/01/15/if-you-implement-iequatable-t-you-still-must-override-object-s-equals-and-gethashcode.html) though, you **must** still implement the standard `Object.Equals` and `Object.GetHashcode` overrides.

Comment: Is there any cast between reference types? I always thought that casts were just "statements" you make to the compiler when you assign some not obvious casts from one kind of object to another. This is, after you compile, that the code wouldn't even know there was a cast there.

Comment: That is true in C++ but not .NET languages which enforce type safety. There is a runtime cast and if the cast does not succeed, an exception is thrown. So there is a small runtime penalty to pay for casting. The compiler can optimize away upcasts For example object o = (object)"string"; But downcasting - string s = (string)o; - must happen at runtime.

Comment: I see. By chance you have any place where I can get that kind of "deeper" information about .NET? Thanks!

Comment: I would recommend CLR via C# by Jeff Richter and C# in Depth by Jon Skeet. As for blogs, Wintellect blogs are good, msdn blogs, etc.

Comment: Does the `IEquatable<T>` interface do anything more than remind a developer to include a  `public bool Equals(T other)`  member in the class or struct?  The presence or absence of the interface makes no difference at run-time.  The overload of `Equals` would appear to be all that is necessary.

Comment: @mikemay it makes a difference for the classes that look for it, usually [EqualityComparer<T>.Default](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.equalitycomparer-1.default?view=net-5.0), which is the canonical default comparer in basically every BCL class that needs one (like `HashSet<T>`)

Comment: [As mentioned here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/collections/comparisons-and-sorts-within-collections#check-for-equality) If the collection is generic, then items are compared for equality by `IEquatable<T>` first and if not implemented by `object.Equals()` .

Answer (score 57):

According to the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131187.aspx):

> If you implement `IEquatable<T>`, you
>   should also override the base class
>   implementations of
>   `Object.Equals(Object)` and `GetHashCode`
>   so that their behavior is consistent
>   with that of the `IEquatable<T>.Equals`
>   method. If you do override
>   `Object.Equals(Object)`, your overridden
>   implementation is also called in calls
>   to the static `Equals(System.Object,
>   System.Object)` method on your class.
>   This ensures that all invocations of
>   the `Equals` method return consistent
>   results.

So it seems that there's no real functional difference between the two except that either could be called depending on how the class is used.  From a performance standpoint, it's better to use the generic version because there's no boxing/unboxing penalty associated with it.

From a logical standpoint, it's also better to implement the interface.  Overriding the object doesn't really tell anyone that your class is actually equatable.  The override may just be a do nothing class or a shallow implementation.  Using the interface explicitly says, "Hey, this thing is valid for equality checking!"  It's just better design.

Comment: Structs should definitely implement iEquatable(of theirOwnType) if they are going to used as keys in a Dictionary or similar collection; it will offer a major performance boost.  Non-inheritable classes will receive a slight performance boost by implementing IEquatable(of theirOwnType).  Inheritable classes should //not// implement IEquatable.

Answer (score 37):

Extending what Josh said with a practical example. +1 to Josh - I was about to write the same in my answer.

```
public abstract class EntityBase : IEquatable<EntityBase>
{
    public EntityBase() { }

    #region IEquatable<EntityBase> Members

    public bool Equals(EntityBase other)
    {
        //Generic implementation of equality using reflection on derived class instance.
        return true;
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        return this.Equals(obj as EntityBase);
    }

    #endregion
}

public class Author : EntityBase
{
    public Author() { }
}

public class Book : EntityBase
{
    public Book() { }
}
```

This way, I have re-usable Equals() method that works out of the box for all my derived classes.

Comment: Just one more question. What is the advantage of using "obj as EntityBase" instead of (EntityBase)obj? Just a matter of style or is there any advantage at all?

Comment: in case of "obj as EntityBase" - if obj is not of type EntityBase, it will pass "null" and continue without any error or exception, But in case of "(EntityBase)obj", it will forcefully try to cast the obj to EntityBase and if the obj is not of type EntityBase, it will throw InvalidCastException. And yes, "as" can only be applied to reference types.

Comment: I understand the answer (generic equals - so strongly typed, and no need of converting to object etc.). But have a question regarding following statement: >>> This way, I have re-usable Equals() method that works out of the box for all my derived classes<<< Isn't it true, if one doesn't implement 'Iequatable<T>', just override 'equals' , this can work for derived types as well, right? just want to make sure what your intent is :)

Comment: Josh's link to Jared Par's blog seems to suggest you also need to override GetHashCode. Is this not the case?

Comment: I don't really get the extra value your implementation provides. Can you clarify the problem that your abstract base class solves?

Comment: @Amicable - yes, whenever you override Object.Equals(Object), you must also override GetHashCode so that containers work.

Answer (score 3):

If we call `object.Equals`, it forces to expensive boxing on value types. This is undesirable in performance-sensitive scenarios. The solution is to use `IEquatable<T>`.

```
public interface IEquatable<T>
{
  bool Equals (T other);
}
```

The idea behind `IEquatable<T>` is that it gives the same result as `object.Equals` but more quickly. The constrain `where T : IEquatable<T>` must be used with generic types like below.

```
public class Test<T> where T : IEquatable<T>
{
  public bool IsEqual (T a, T b)
  {
    return a.Equals (b); // No boxing with generic T
  }
}
```

otherwise, it binds to `slower object.Equals()`.