# Equals() IEquatable How ther are related to each other? 

Tags: c#, equals

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What's the difference between IEquatable and just overriding Object.Equals() ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2734914/whats-the-difference-between-iequatable-and-just-overriding-object-equals)

I know that all classes in C# are deived from object and object has a virtual method named `Equals()`.

Why should I impliment `IEquatable`? Why not to override `object.Equals`?

Comment: Same as [What's the difference between IEquatable and just overriding Object.Equals() ?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2734914/whats-the-difference-between-iequatable-and-just-overriding-object-equals).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`IEquatable<T>` defines

```
bool Equals(T other)
```

While object's Equals defines

```
bool Equals(object other)
```

So defining IEquatable for your class allows you to do an easier comparison of two items of the same class without having to cast to the current type.  A lot of times you'll see people implement IEquatable and then override object's Equals to call IEquatable's equals:

```
public class SomeClass : IEquatable<SomeClass>
{
    public bool Equals(SomeClass other)
    {
        // actual compare
    }

    public override bool Equals(object other)
    {
        // cross-call to IEquatable's equals.
        return Equals(other as SomeClass); 
    }
}
```

In addition, you can define equality between other types as well.  Like make Fraction implement IEquatable

Comment: @Andrew: Hah, another Hare?  Wonder if we're related anywhere in our ancestry...

Comment: Very cool! My middle name is Michael as well - small world :)

Comment: Applying IEquatable<T> to structures is a big win, since it allows them to be compared without boxing.  Applying IEquatable<T> to *sealed* immutable reference types is a small win since it eliminates the need for type-checking and/or type-casting.  Applying it to unsealed types is dangerous, because a derived type which overrides Object.Equals without overriding IEquatable<T> will expose different equality-test methods to different consumers.  That might not be a horrible thing if IEquatable<T> included its own GetHashCode, but it doesn't.

Comment: And you both are separated by exactly 100k :)