# XUnit Assertion for checking equality of objects

Tags: c#, xunit.net, xunit

I am using XUnit framework to test my C# code.

Is there any assert method available in this framework which does the object comparison? My intention is to check for equality of each of the object's public and private member variables.

I tried those alternatives but seldom it works:

```
1) bool IsEqual = (Obj1 == Obj2)
2) Assert.Same(Obj1, Obj2) which I couldnt understand what happens internally
```

Comment: There is "deep comparison" in xUnit. You'll have to implement IEquatable<T> for your objects, and then Assert.Equals will work.

Comment: `Assert.Same()` compares by reference; it asserts that `Obj1` and `Obj2` are the **same** object rather than just **looking** the same.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You need to have a custom comparer to achieve this, when you compare objects otherwise they are checked on the basis of whether they are referring to the same object in memory. To override this behavior you need to override the `Equals` and `GetHashCode` method and then you could do:

```
Assert.True(obj1.Equals(obj2));
```

Here is an MSDN page abt overloading Equals method: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173147(v=vs.80).aspx

Also apt the comment on the question: [What's the difference between IEquatable and just overriding Object.Equals()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2734914/whats-the-difference-between-iequatable-and-just-overriding-object-equals)

Comment: I understand that by implementing custom "Equals" method, this check can be performed. But is there any method to do a blind byte comparison, which will make the check easier? This is because I will end up having an "Equals" implementation in "Software under test" just for unit testing sake.

Comment: I tried using serialization methods to convert both objects to a byte array and it worked. But it comes with a constraint of adding [serializable] attribute to my class which has private member variables. I guess this is not good in design perspective

Comment: I am against overriding these two methods just for unit tests.

Comment: And what happens when your logic for business rules equality differs from your logic for test equality?

Comment: you just need to pass an IEqualityComparer as the third argument

`            Assert.Equal(expectedCar, actualCar, CarComparer);
`

Comment: This answer is only useful as long as the link works (which it no longer does).

Answer (score 110):

I had similar issue, but then luckily I am already using

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
```

So I just had to serialize it to json object then compare as string.

```
var obj1Str = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj1);
var obj2Str = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj2);
Assert.Equal(obj1Str, obj2Str );
```

Comment: I consider this more useful than implementing an Equals method because I'd like my assert failure to tell me something about what was wrong. What I'd like ideally is to have something that can traverse an object tree and accumulate information about which properties/subtrees are non-equal and fail with that information.

Comment: @RikkiGibson isn't implementing Equals just the right way to do it? Just add exceptions to a list in the equals for every property that is different, then at the end either return true or throw all the exceptions

Comment: Yes, but it can be painstaking to do case by case, which is why I’ve tended to look for reflection based solutions in the past when comparing trees of plain old objects, primitives and collections.

Comment: @RikkiGibson There are some NuGet packages that do what you want. See my answer.

Comment: There is no warranty that these objects will be serialized the same way, there is some risk here.

Comment: There is now `Assert.Equivalent`. See Adam T's answer.

Answer (score 38):

[FluentAssertions](https://github.com/fluentassertions/fluentassertions) library has some pretty powerful comparison logic inside.

```
myObject.ShouldBeEquivalentTo(new { SomeProperty = "abc", SomeOtherProperty = 23 });
```

You can even use this to assert on part of "myObject".
However, it might not help you with the private fields.

Comment: The current version of the library seem to using the following API: `actual.Should().BeEquivalentTo(expected);`

Comment: Out from under my rock I crawl, face the xUnit test monster I must... It makes so little sense, says I. My inner coding child always had to be reminded that unit test tantrums are so totally not age appropriate. Well, that was before I discovered FluentAssertions. That day was today. And you, @AdrianPetrescu have the heartfelt appreciation of this bleary-eyed developer.

Answer (score 38):

As of Xunit 2.4.2, released 1 Aug 2022, this feature is implemented as Assert.Equivalent.

Example:

```
Assert.Equivalent(Obj1, Obj2);
```

or

```
Assert.Equivalent(Obj1, Obj2, strict:true)
```

See release notes: https://xunit.net/releases/v2/2.4.2

Comment: The release note link currently: https://xunit.net/releases/v2/2.4.2

Comment: Unfortunately it fails when checking collections items position

Answer (score 20):

There are NuGet packages that do this for you.
Here are two examples that I personally use.

1. [DeepEqual](https://github.com/jamesfoster/DeepEqual):

   ```
   object1.ShouldDeepEqual(object2);
   ```
2. [ExpectedObjects](https://github.com/derekgreer/expectedObjects/):

   ```
   [Fact]
   public void RetrievingACustomer_ShouldReturnTheExpectedCustomer()
   {
     // Arrange
     var expectedCustomer = new Customer
     {
       FirstName = "Silence",
       LastName = "Dogood",
       Address = new Address
       {
         AddressLineOne = "The New-England Courant",
         AddressLineTwo = "3 Queen Street",
         City = "Boston",
         State = "MA",
         PostalCode = "02114"
       }                                            
     }.ToExpectedObject();


     // Act
     var actualCustomer = new CustomerService().GetCustomerByName("Silence", "Dogood");

     // Assert
     expectedCustomer.ShouldEqual(actualCustomer);
   }
   ```

Comment: Any opinions on pros/cons of these libraries?

Comment: @WillP. DeepEqual doesn't have official .NET Standard/Core support (yet). It works but it could cause issues.
Otherwise they're pretty much the same. ExpectedObjects has a few more features though like Partial or Custom Comparisons. 
That's why I use ExpectedObjects in pretty much all of my projects nowadays but it's more a personal preference.

Answer (score 10):

I know this is an old question, but since I stumbled upon it I figured I'd weigh in with a new solution that's available (at least in xunit 2.3.1 in a .net Core 2.0 solution).

I'm not sure when it was introduced, but there is now an overloaded form of `.Equal` that accepts an instance of `IEqualityComparer<T>` as the third parameter. You can create a custom comparer in your unit test without polluting your code with it.

The following code can be invoked like this: `Assert.Equal(expectedParameters, parameters, new CustomComparer<ParameterValue>());`

XUnit natively appears to stop processing a test as soon as a failure is encountered, so throwing a new `EqualException` from within our comparer seems to be in line with how XUnit works out of the box.

```
public class CustomComparer<T> : IEqualityComparer<T>
{
    public bool Equals(T expected, T actual)
    {
        var props = typeof(T).GetProperties(BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
        foreach (var prop in props)
        {
            var expectedValue = prop.GetValue(expected, null);
            var actualValue = prop.GetValue(actual, null);
            if (!expectedValue.Equals(actualValue))
            {
                throw new EqualException($"A value of \"{expectedValue}\" for property \"{prop.Name}\"",
                    $"A value of \"{actualValue}\" for property \"{prop.Name}\"");
            }
        }

        return true;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(T parameterValue)
    {
        return Tuple.Create(parameterValue).GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

**Edit: I found that comparing the actual and expected values with `!=` was not effective for certain types (I'm sure there's a better explanation involving the difference between reference types and value types, but that's not for today). I updated the code to use the `.Equals` method to compare the two values and that seems to work much better.**

Comment: This works but I'd rather just use a NuGet package that does a similar thing. Less code that I have to worry about

Comment: You should not `throw` on the `Equals`. It can screw up `Assert.DoesNotContain` since it expects to get false on each of the entries. You better return `false` instead.

Comment: @maracuja-juice less code indeed, but a dependency on an external package, and all the cyber risks that go with it...

Comment: Since this answer continues to get upvotes more than 3 years later, I'll go ahead and point out that I created an open source NuGet package to do this and it's a lot more robust than what I've included here.

Source: https://github.com/engineer-andrew/ea-xunit-helpers
Package: https://www.nuget.org/packages/EAXUnitHelpers.Comparison/

Comment: @Necriis Or if you don't want an external package: Make your own function so that the code is encapsulated and easier to use instead of always having to use a CustomComparer.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another implementation of the IEqualityComparer interface with a really [GenericComparer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6694508/how-to-use-the-iequalitycomparer/71047520#71047520)

And for asserting that 2 lists of same type are equal, regardless of the list container, you can add this extension:

```
public static bool IsEqualTo<T>(this IEnumerable<T> list, IEnumerable<T> expected) where T : class
{
    if (!list.HasSameLengthThan<T>(expected))
        return false;

    Assert.Equal(expected, list, new GenericComparer<T>());
    return true;
}
```