# Compare two class objects in C#

Tags: c#, unit-testing

I am trying to compare two class Objects in my unit tests but getting exception even though the fields are identical.

```
[TestMethod]
public async Task getResult()
{
var expectedResult = new List<myClass>(){
    new myClass(){
        Id = 1
        Name = "updatedName"
    }
}
// here I am calling POST method to update the name
// won't include the full code because of brevity

// now getting the result
var actualResult = await this.getResult(1) // getting the result of the above Id

Assert.Equal(expectedResult, actualResult)
}
```

Exception I get:

```
myClass
{
    Id = 1
    Name = "updatedName"
} because myClass should match, but found
myClass
{
    Id = 1
    Name = "updatedName"
}
```

I am confused as all the fields are identical, so why are they not matching?

Comment: the new `record` feature of c#9 makes this work as you expect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Assert.Equal` relies on the object's `.Equals` method ([see here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object.equals?view=net-6.0)). When creating your own classes, you have an option to *override* this method and add your own logic of comparing two objects equality (e.g., field by field equality checking).

If you do not override it, there is a default `.Equals` inherited from `Object`, which is equivalent to `.ReferenceEquals`: it returns true if the two objects have the same *reference* and false otherwise. The only situation when the two objects have the same reference is when it's *the same* object.

In your case, you can either define the `.Equals` override for your class ([e.g., see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2363143/whats-the-best-strategy-for-equals-and-gethashcode)) or you can try to follow some of the advice given in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11135337/xunit-assertion-for-checking-equality-of-objects) on how to perform **deep equality checking** of two objects. Third option is to create a separate class inherited from `IEqualityComparer`, which will purely provide the equality checking logic for your object while not being a part of your class codebase (for example, [see this article](https://khalidabuhakmeh.com/write-and-use-iequalitycomparer)).