# EqualityComparer<T>.Default doesn't return the derived EqualityComparer

Tags: c#, iequalitycomparer

I have a class Person, and created an equality comperer class derived from EqualityComparer < Person >. Yet the default EqualityComparer doesn't call the Equals function of my equality comparer

According to MSDN [EqualityComparer < T > .Default property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms224763(v=vs.110).aspx):

> The Default property checks whether type T implements the System.IEquatable interface and, if so, returns an EqualityComparer that uses that implementation. Otherwise, it returns an EqualityComparer that uses the overrides of Object.Equals and Object.GetHashCode provided by T.

In the (simplified) example below, class Person does not implement implement System.IEquatable < Person >. So I'd expect that PersonComparer.Default would return an instance of PersonComparer.

Yet PersonComparer.Equals is not called. There is no debug output and the returned value is false.

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class PersonComparer : EqualityComparer<Person>
{
    public override bool Equals(Person x, Person y)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("PersonComparer.Equals called");
        return true;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode(Person obj)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("PersonComparer.GetHasCode called");
        return obj.Name.GetHashCode();
    }
}

public static void Main()
{
    Person x = new Person() { Name = "x" };
    Person y = new Person() { Name = "x" };
    bool b1 = PersonComparer.Default.Equals(x, y);
}
```

**Question: What am I doing wrong?**

In case you might wonder why I don't want to implement IEquatable < Person >.

My problem is comparable with the comparison of strings. Sometimes you want two strings to be equal if they are exactly the same strings, sometimes you want to ignore case, and sometimes you want to treat characters as óò etc all as if they are the character o.

In my case: I store a Person in something, which might be a database, but it might as well be a File or a MemoryStream. Upon return I get an identifier, which in case of a database is of course the primary key. With this key I am able to retrieve an object with the same values.

I want to test this in a unit Test: I you put something in it, you should get a key that can be used to retrieve the item. Alas, the database doesn't return the same Person, but a derived class of Person (At least when using EF 6). So I can't use the normal IEquatable, which should return false if the objects are not of the same type. That's why I wanted to use a special comparer, one that declares two Persons equal if they have the same values for the properties, even if they are both different derived classes from Person. Very comparable as a string comparer that accepts O and o and ó to be equal

Comment: The documentation quoted gives you the answer - it uses a comparer which uses the `Equals(object)` and `GetHashCode` methods on `Person`. Why do you think it will use `PersonComparer`?

Comment: You just need to call `new PersonComparer()` instead of `PersonComparer.Default.`.

Comment: "Sometimes you want two strings to be equal if they are exactly the same strings, sometimes you want…". Yeah, and when you have a bunch of "sometimes" then you might have a "default", which is what `Person` should do by itself and which `EqualityComparer<Person>.Default` would hence make use of.

Comment: "So I can't use the normal IEquatable, which should return false if the objects are not of the same type." Why would you define it that way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have mixed up some things, but it's not surprising since, everyone must admit that the .NET Framework has [a bit too many possibilities](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32380596/5114784) for equality comparison.

You should implement the `IEqualityComparer<T>` only if you want to specify special comparison logic for specific situations, such as to a `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`, for example.

The `EqualityComparer<T>` is confusingly an overridable type in .NET; however, it is not intended that you override it, and there's no use in doing so. It provides a default comparer for generic types and it will call your `IEquatable<T>` implementation if you use `T` in a `List<T>` (`Contains`, `IndexOf`, etc.) or when `T` is a key of a dictionary and you didn't pass any custom `IEqualityComparer` to the dictionary.

Answer (score 4):

Let's re-read the quote you added:

> The Default property checks whether **type T implements the `System.IEquatable` interface** and, if so, **returns an EqualityComparer
>   that uses that implementation.**

So, the `Default` property looks for **an implementation of `IEqutable<T>`**, which your `Person` does not provide.

If the object doesn't implement `IEquatable<T>`, then:

> Otherwise, it returns an EqualityComparer that **uses the overrides of Object.Equals and Object.GetHashCode provided by T.**

Which shows you exactly why `object.Equals` and `object.GetHashCode` are the ones being called. You have two choices, either use `new PersonComparer().Equals()`, or implement `IEquatable<Person>` on your type (if such a single implementation is possible).

Comment: Do you mean that the phrase "uses the overrides of ... by T" doesn't mean that the EqualityComparer.Equals(T x, T y) is called? Why do they exist then?

Comment: @HaraldDutch The overrides of `object.Equals` and `object.GetHashCode` would only exist if you override `IEquatable<T>`. Not sure why the documentation expresses it this way, but they basically mean "it will defer to the default `object` implementation for these two methods".

Comment: @HaraldDutch The implementation of `CreateComparer` inside `EqualityComparer` shows you that if it doesn't answer certain criteria's, [an `ObjectEqualityComparer` is returned](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/equalitycomparer.cs,ac282b3e1817bb9b). Which will end up using `object.Equals` if the type has no custom `Equals` implementation.

Answer (score 2):

That is because the `Default` property of `EqualityComparer<T>` does not return a `PersonComparer`, but a `ObjectEqualityComparer<T>`. And that `ObjectEqualityComparer<T>`, as you referenced the documentation, compares using the `Equals` on `Person`.

See [the actual source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/equalitycomparer.cs,47). At line 89 it returns the `ObjectEqualityComparer<T>`.

There is actually nothing wrong with your code, as you can see when you actually try to run your code on an instance of `PersonComparer`:

```
bool b1 = new PersonComparer().Equals(x, y);
```

Comment: I created the two overrides, and did not implement IEquatable. Why are my overrides not called then?

Comment: Because it is not the same object. `PersonComparer` != `ObjectEqualityComparer<Person>`. Just as the documentation says.

Comment: Agreed, but I expected that the ObjectEqualtyComparer would call PersonComparer.Equals(Person, Person)