# I have a class A<T> : IEnumerable<T>, I want to add IEquatable<A<T>> if T : IEquatable<T>. How can I do that and keep the IEnumerable as well?

Tags: c#, inheritance, interface

I have a Tree-type class `Foo<T>` with its interface `IFoo<T>`.

I want `Foo<T>` to be able to implement `IEquatable<Foo<T>>` when `T : IEquatable<T>` **(or more generally if `T : I<T>` i might want `Foo<T> : I<Foo<T>>` in addition of other implemented interfaces)**.

I tried the pseudo-following code :

```
public interface IFoo<T> : IEnumerable<IFoo<T>>
...


public class Foo<T> : IFoo<T>
...


public interface IFooTwo<T> : IFoo<T>, IEquatable<IFooTwo<T>>
    where T : IEquatable<T>
...

public class FooTwo<T> : IFooTwo<T> {
... // I implement Equals
    public bool NewMethod(FooTwo<T> Other) { ... }
}
```

So now I have succesfully implemented `Equals` (I also overrided the geniric Equals, etc.).

But `FooTwo<T>` now does not implement `IEnumerable<IFooTwo<T>>` (instead it implements `IEnumerable<IFoo<T>>`).

So I have two questions :

1. Is there a better way for me to organize my code in order to achieve my goal (if `T : IEquatable<T>` I want to be able to implement `IEquatable<Foo<T>>` for `Foo<T>`) ? A sort of conditional `where`.
2. How can I make `FooTwo<T>` implements `IEnumerable <FooTwo<T>>` using
   `Foo<T> IEnumerable` implementation in a quick and easy way ?

edit :

In the special case of `IEquatable<Foo<T>>`, I have a simple answer for question 1. I can test if `T:IEquatable<T>` and change my implementation of `IEquatable<Foo<T>>` if needed. However I am still wondering how to do it in a more general case.

Comment: How do you recon that it implements `IEnumerable<Foo<T>>` and not `IEnumerable<IFoo<T>>`?

Comment: You are right, edited

Comment: **please** pay attention to the preview pane when editing your question, and especially when you're trying to discuss generic type parameters. I've already fixed your code once, I'm not in the mood to do it again for your edit (which, please try and read as it currently displays, and see how much sense it makes)

Comment: I have no idea what is the problem with my edit, everything seems fine to me.

Comment: **Read** your question. The first line of your edit says "In the special case of IEquatable>, I have a simple answer for question 1.". Did you really mean to say IEquatable>? No, You meant to have a generic parameter there. But because you've not marked that piece up as code, it's interpreted it as an HTML tag instead and swallowed part of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since what you're essentially doing is trying to have some `IFoo<T>` objects be `IEquatable<T>` and some not, and that's clearly at odds with the type system, I'd avoid `IEquatable<T>` entirely.  Use `IEqualityComparer<T>`.  Simply provide a method that creates an `IEqualityComparer<IFoo<T>>` when given an `IEqualityComparer<T>` (or using the default comparer for `T`, if you want).

By doing this none of the `IFoo<T>` objects are obligated to compare themselves, but anyone is able to create a means of comapring `IFoo<T>` objects as long as they know how to compare the underlying objects.

This also removes the need for multiple implementations of `IFoo<T>` entirely, simplifying the entire code base dramatically, and removing your other problem entirely.

> How can I make `FooTwo<T>` implements `IEnumerable<FooTwo<T>>` using
>       `Foo<T> IEnumerable` implementation in a quick and easy way?

(If you choose to not follow my suggestion for changing how you handle equality:)

If you know that all of the items in the sequence are in fact of the correct type, you can simply use `Cast<FooTwo<T>>()` on the sequence.

If the items in the sequence aren't actually `FooTwo<T>` objects then you'll need to project the items into a new sequence, where you map each `IFoo<T>` item to a `FooTwo<T>` item.

Answer (score 2):

For question 1, you should think about whether you really need this. `IEquatable<T>` [mostly exists for performance reasons relating to value types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2734914/whats-the-difference-between-iequatable-and-just-overriding-object-equals). In your case, there shouldn't really be any reason that you need to make sure you're using the `IEquatable` equals rather than the object one. This is what, for example, `Tuple<T>` does. Then you can just have a single interface with no constraint:

```
public interface IFoo<T> : IEnumerable<IFoo<T>>, IEquatable<IFoo<T>>
```

For question 2, you may not need this either. `IEnumerable<T>` is [covariant](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ee207183.aspx), meaning that if you have an `IEnumerable<A>`, you can assign this to a variable of type `IEnumerable<B>`, as long as `A` can be assigned to `B`. In your case, this means if you have, e.g., a method that takes an `IEnumerable<IFoo<T>>` will also accept an `IEnumerable<IFooTwo<T>>` since `IFooTwo<T> : IFoo<T>`

However, if you want to have, say, a class `MyFoo<T> : IFoo<T>` to be of type `IEnumerable<MyFoo<T>>`, there's no way to do that automatically. This is because it's perfectly possible to have a valid implementation of `IEnumerable<IFoo<T>>` which isn't also an implementation of `IEnumerable<MyFoo<T>>`. You should probably treat this requirement as a design smell and try to avoid it.

Comment: I see now for question 1 that I could test if T : IEquatable<T> and change my IEquatable<IFoo<T>>.Equals implementation in function. What if it is another interface however than IEquatable ? 

But for question 2, I can't enumerate my FooTwo<T> class as FooTwo<T> which I want to do. (e.g. `foreach(FooTwo<T> t in x)` will fail with x `FooTwo<T>`

Comment: @CelestinSaint-Loup Well you could always just add ` : IEnumerable<FooTwo<T>>` to the declaration of `FooTwo`. Obviously that won't work when `x` (in your example) has static type `IFooTwo` rather than `FooTwo`, but that isn't possible.

Comment: @CelestinSaint-Loup But there's a reason you're finding these things hard- you're trying to work against the type system rather than with it. You should review your design to try to see if you can get rid of these requirements