# IEquatable, how to implement this properly

Tags: c#, .net, c#-2.0

I am using .net 2.0 and c# and I have implemented the IEquatible interface in my class like this:-

```
public MyClass() :  IEquatable<MyClass>
{
    Guid m_id = Guid.NewGuid();

    public Guid Id
    {
        get
        {
            return m_id;
        }
    }

    #region IEquatable<MyClass> Members

    public bool Equals(MyClass other)
    {
        if (this.Id == other.Id)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Is this bad programming practice? I've read that I also need to implement Object.Equals and Object.GetHashCode as well, but I am not sure why.

I want to be able to check that an instance of MyClass is not already contained in a generic list of type MyClass. Why does the framework only suggests that you implement Equals only?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The implementation can be shortened to: `return this.Id == other.Id;`.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? With the code posted above, each instance of MyClass will be initialised with a new Guid, which will mean that every instance is unique and not equatable to another instance, is this the desired behaviour?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a complete IEquatable implementation reference?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1307493/is-there-a-complete-iequatable-implementation-reference). Also, check [Understanding IEquatable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/411500/understanding-iequatable).

Comment: I agree. If each instance has a unique ID, then `Object.ReferenceEquals` will work the same way (unless there is a possibility to clone an instance of `MyClass`).

Comment: @Oded What if _other_ is null? :)

Comment: @AmarPalsapure - Same `NullReferenceException` that the code posted by the OP would produce.

Comment: Sorry perhaps my example is a bad one, say if I had a person class and I had 2 simple properties such as Name (string) and Age (int), using IEquatable, would I only have to implement Equals and test whether other's Name and Age are equal to this (the current instance), or is there more work to do?

Answer (score 2):

You can check if your list contains an item using a custom predicate for the criteria, using LINQ. In that case you don't need to override `Equals` nor implement `IEquatable`:

```
// check if the list contains an item with a specific ID
bool found = someList.Any(item => item.ID == someId);
```

Overriding `Equals` (with `GetHashCode`) and implementing `IEquatable` is useful if you need to store your item in a `Dictionary` or a `Hashtable`.

Answer (score 2):

> Is this bad programming practice?

Implementing `IEquatable<T>` is great, even more so for structs, but merely doing that much is not enough.

> I've read that I also need to implement Object.Equals

[Read it here why..](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13741737/is-it-important-to-override-equals-if-im-implementing-iequatablet)

> and Object.GetHashCode as well, but I am not sure why.

[Read it here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/371328/why-is-it-important-to-override-gethashcode-when-equals-method-is-overridden) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2265503/why-do-i-need-to-override-the-equals-and-hashcode-methods-in-java). Seriously, these have been discussed so many times, and it is pretty simple.. In short, you need it for collection types that deals with hashes like `Dictionary<,>` or `HashSet<>`

> I want to be able to check that an instance of MyClass is not already contained in a generic list of type MyClass. Why does the framework only suggests that you implement Equals only?

Depends on the collection type. For a `List<T>`, it will check equality merely based on how you have defined `Equals` method, say for `Contains` method. For most scenario you will need `Equals` only. But if you have a `HashSet<T>` then absence and presence checks will utilize hash of your objects. Framework indeed asks us to implement good hashing approaches (without re-inventing the wheel) [at appropriate places](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.gethashcode.aspx).

> Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Do as below, but you have to overload operators `==` and `!=` only if it make sense to you. Seeing your class I assumed its ok to have value semantics for your class. Otherwise just ignore that part (if `==` should mean reference equality)... Getting hashcode from your guid would suffice, provided that is all you need to test equality.

```
public sealed class MyClass : IEquatable<MyClass>
{
    Guid m_id = Guid.NewGuid();

    public Guid Id { get { return m_id; } }

    public bool Equals(MyClass other)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(this, other))
            return true;

        if (ReferenceEquals(null, other))
            return false;

        return Id == other.Id; 
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        return Equals(obj as MyClass);
    }

    public static bool operator ==(MyClass lhs, MyClass rhs)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(lhs, null))
            return ReferenceEquals(rhs, null);

        return lhs.Equals(rhs);
    }

    public static bool operator !=(MyClass lhs, MyClass rhs)
    {
        return !(lhs == rhs);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return Id.GetHashCode();
    }   
}
```

**To not get it wrong, make use of the snippet available [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/104309/661933):** For a good overview [see this SO thread.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/104158/what-is-best-practice-for-comparing-two-instances-of-a-reference-type)